Recover data from a raid 1 disk
i would like to recover some data from a disk which was part of a MD RAID 1 Array in an old fileserver.
Drive 1 had a HW issue and it seems that drive 2 stuck in a Rebuilding State.
My idea was to get drive 2 and  with an USB - Sata adapter get the files from it.
On top of the raid is a LVM partition. So i couldn`t just mount the partiton.
root@fedora:~# parted -l
Model: ST1000NM 0033-9ZM173 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size   Type      File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  512MB   511MB  primary   ext2         boot
 2      513MB   1000GB  999GB  extended
 5      513MB   1000GB  999GB  logical                lvm




As i see the disk is in offline / rebuilding state.
root@fedora:~# mdadm --examine /dev/sda
/dev/sda:
          Magic : de11de11
        Version : 01.00.00
Controller GUID : 44656C6C:20202020:34333130:30564200:006001F0:ED640012
                  (Dell    43100VB)
 Container GUID : 44656C6C:20202020:10000073:10281F4E:41640BC0:C1D7FF65
                  (Dell     10/06/14 11:14:08)
            Seq : 00000035
  Redundant hdr : yes
  Virtual Disks : 1

      VD GUID[0] : 44656C6C:20202020:10000073:10281F4E:406DA2EF:730D338D
                  (Dell     04/02/14 13:29:19)
         unit[0] : 0
        state[0] : Degraded, Consistent
   init state[0] : Not Initialised
       access[0] : Read/Write
         Name[0] : 
 Raid Devices[0] : 2 (0@0K 1@0K)
   Chunk Size[0] : 128 sectors
   Raid Level[0] : RAID1
  Device Size[0] : 976224256
   Array Size[0] : 976224256

 Physical Disks : 63
      Number    RefNo      Size       Device      Type/State
         0    88caeaba  976224256K                 active/Online
         1    67e3dd7c  976224256K /dev/sda        active/Offline, Rebuilding


root@fedora:~# mdadm --misc --detail /dev/md126
/dev/md126:
         Container : /dev/md/ddf0, member 0
        Raid Level : raid1
      Raid Devices : 2
     Total Devices : 0

             State : active, FAILED, Not Started 
    Active Devices : 0
    Failed Devices : 0

Consistency Policy : unknown

    Container GUID : 44656C6C:20202020:10000073:10281F4E:41640BC0:C1D7FF65
                  (Dell     10/06/14 11:14:08)
               Seq : 00000035
     Virtual Disks : 1

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       -       0        0        0      removed
       -       0        0        1      removed
root@fedora:~# mdadm --misc --detail /dev/md127
/dev/md127:
           Version : ddf
        Raid Level : container
     Total Devices : 1

   Working Devices : 1

    Container GUID : 44656C6C:20202020:10000073:10281F4E:41640BC0:C1D7FF65
                  (Dell     10/06/14 11:14:08)
               Seq : 00000035
     Virtual Disks : 1

     Member Arrays : /dev/md126

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice

       -       8        0        -        /dev/sda


Is there a way to get out of this state and mount this 1 disk only to get the files?
Thank you!

If the data is actually there (the drive was not kicked from the array and the array did not die mid-rebuild to this drive) then "it should just work" ... what happens if you try to access it directly (not using mdadm at all)? Make a full ddrescue image of it first, just in case.

So I wanted to boot the server with just one disk but it didn't saw the disk, so maybe it died during rebuild. now I only wanted do rescue some files. They had a backup but it missed one excel sheet :) . Thank you for your comment though! I will try to get the file with ddrescue / or testdisk!
